# Operator>> overloading to assign private pointer array

Tags: c++

im trying to use the overloaded `operator>>` to put the input stream into a `char*` array.

Valgrind shows me that i get an `Invalid write of size 1` at the line im assigning the input stream to my `char* array`.

My Code for this looks like the following. (Shorted)

In my string.h im defining the functions.

```
#ifndef STRING_H_INCLUDED
#define STRING_H_INCLUDED
#include<iostream>
#include<istream>
#include<ostream>
class string{
public:
    string(char* = nullptr);
    ~string();
    string(const string&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&,string&);
    void copyStr(char*);
    char* getContent() const;
    ...
private:
    string& operator=(const string&);
    char* s = nullptr;
};


#endif // STRING_H_INCLUDED
```

The actual c++ file looks like this.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ostream>
#include "string.h"

string::string(char* i){
       if(i == nullptr){
           s = new char[1];
           s[0] = '\0';
       }else{
           s = new char[getCharl(i)+1];
           copyStr(i);
       }
   }
   string::~string(){
       if(s != nullptr){
           delete[] s;
       }
   }

   string::string(const string& x){
       copyStr(x.getContent());
   }

   std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, string& arg){
       is >> arg.getContent();
       return is;
   }

   void string::copyStr(char* i){
       unsigned  index    = 0;
       delete[] s;
       char* tmp = new char[getCharl(i)+1];
       while (i[index] != '\0'){
           tmp[index] = i[index];
           index++;
       }
       tmp[index] = '\0';
       s = tmp;
   }

   char* string::getContent() const{
       return s;
   }
   ...
```

Maybe someone would be so kind to create a small example to show me how it works with a little explanation.

Cheers!

Edit:

Added the `getContent()` function.

Comment: what's `getContent`?

Comment: and you should not implement `operator>>` as member.

Comment: @appleapple thanks for pointing out the missing function!

Comment: @appleapple i need to. Im not allowed to change the main class for this project

Comment: ah, it's not member, I see it now, it just some weird indention.

Comment: What happens when the user inputs a string longer than the space currently allocated for `s`?  You have no checks for that.

Comment: @NateEldredge how do i check for that? Can i iterate is somehow and find an end to create a new array and assign it to `s`? Some thing like `while(is){cnt++}; delete s; s = new char[cnt]; `

Comment: Unrelated: You don't need `if(s != nullptr)` before doing `delete[] s;` Deleting a `nullptr` doesn't do anything

Comment: your string kind of simplistic by stripping down every faculty actual string had which makes proper code for >> quite complex

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie thats a good one thanks ! Haven't found this myself. Im gonna mark this as a duplicate then.